# C# Application-Wide Left Mouse Click Event

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to play a sound when the left mouse button is clicked anywhere in my form without having to place Mouse click events on every single control in the form. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Consider looking at WPF instead of WinForms. WPF events are automatically bubbled up to parent controls, so this would be trivial.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can detect the Windows notification before it is dispatched to the control with the focus with the IMessageFilter interface.  Make it look similar to this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form, IMessageFilter {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        Application.AddMessageFilter(this);
        this.FormClosed += delegate { Application.RemoveMessageFilter(this); };
    }

    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m) {
        // Trap WM_LBUTTONDOWN
        if (m.Msg == 0x201) {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("BEEP!");
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

This works for any form in your project, not just the main one.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! Oh and the value for the left mouse button for me was `m.Msg == 0x0201`

Answer (score 4):

This should do the trick

```
const int WM_PARENTNOTIFY = 0x210;
const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x201;

protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == WM_LBUTTONDOWN || (m.Msg == WM_PARENTNOTIFY && (int)m.WParam == WM_LBUTTONDOWN)) 
         DoIt();
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Comment: Awesome beans. Been searching ages for this + sooo simple. Cheers dude.

Answer (score 0):

[This project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx) may be overkill for your needs (since it hooks global mouse events, not just ones on your form), but I think it shows the basics of what you need.

Comment: It's useful occasionally to globally hook mouse or keyboard... but never hook globally what you can process locally.

Answer (score 0):

Case WM_PARENTNOTIFY
   Select Case Wparam 
       Case 513 ' WM_LBUTTODOWN 
         PlaySoundA
   End Select

Using For Vb Or Vba