# c# get clicked element detail on global

Tags: c#, winforms, addeventlistener, mouselistener

I want to listen global click and keyboard events with C#.

I have used MouseKeyboardActivityMonitor package from Nuget, but it gives x-y coordinates. I want to get target element and the window the element is belongs to detail instead.

Can you show me a way how to achieve this. By the way, I found out that Microsoft has a package named UI Automation Elements but I am not if it related to my solution and if it is so, can I use it with Windows Forms APP?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7934629/2720343 this question might have some relevant detail.

Comment: Thanks but I already can listen to such mouse event.